# Sequence-to-sequence learning with real numbers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, sequence, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

TensorFlow has a tutorial on [sequence to sequence models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq) shows how to translate English to French.

Is it possible to use real numbers instead of words in these models?

Comment: Yes, they are actually **designed** to work with numbers, words are tricky to make it work, thus in the end we just embed them as vectors. Just follow the tutorial and skip the embeding part, since you do not need to do that anymore.

Comment: Hi rhombidodecahedron, any luck on seq-to-seq learning with real numbers?

Comment: Hi Lejlot, I have similar problem. For both input and output sequences, the item components are numerical values. For instance, an input sequence can be [0.0001, -0.9995, 21.002, 0, -1000], etc. Do you think sequence-to-sequence can handle this kind of use case? Any suggestions and related research paper are really appreciated.

Comment: The tensorflow seq2seq model expects a vector of numbers from the range (-1 to 1) as an embedding for each item in the vocabulary. Typically your corpus is converted into an array of numbers i.e. indexed using the vocabulary you obtain from the corpus. And this indexed corpus along with the embedding matrix is passed as an embedding lookup.

Comment: @shyampadia if you submit this as an answer with a minimal working example then I will happily accept it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the vocabulary contains the following words

**[hello:0, a:1, the:2, what:3, is:4, problem:5, there:6, it:7, this:8, listen:9]**

since a word only appears once in the vocabulary we can use its respective index as a reference.
so a sentence like

**listen there is a problem**

will be converted into an array of indices like

**[9, 6, 4, 1, 5]**

so this is how a single input sentence can be represented using such embeddings. This vocabulary embedding with the corresponding indices is fed into the network along with a list of these indexed sentences i.e. indexed corpus.

But this is not going to cut it since your network also needs to learn the common relationships among words it requires some more semantic information. This can be achieved using word2vec. You can use trained word2vec and get vectors for all the words in your vocabulary and associate them with these indices and use this as your embedding lookup instead of the word2index dictionary.

Now you can map all of the word indices to their corresponding word vector generated using word2vec and store it in an embedding matrix where the row index is the word index and each row is a fixed length word vector corresponding to that word. And then feed this information to your network in the form a feed dict.

Alternatively, you can also consider word senses or features(combination of word, pos tag and ner tag) and create a vocabulary and then create a similar word2index and embedding matrix